# out of memory using customized view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

I am trying to build an android application that implements a custom viewpager but the problem is memory overflow.

This is my logcat

```
06-03 22:04:53.837: I/dalvikvm-heap(21165): Clamp target GC heap from 102.937MB to 96.000MB
06-03 22:04:53.838: D/dalvikvm(21165): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 175K, 2% free 97183K/98188K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
06-03 22:04:53.839: I/dalvikvm-heap(21165): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 640016-byte allocation
06-03 22:04:53.877: I/dalvikvm-heap(21165): Clamp target GC heap from 102.907MB to 96.000MB
06-03 22:04:53.883: D/dalvikvm(21165): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 95K, 2% free 97087K/98188K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
06-03 22:04:53.883: E/dalvikvm-heap(21165): Out of memory on a 640016-byte allocation.
06-03 22:04:53.883: I/dalvikvm(21165): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
06-03 22:04:53.883: I/dalvikvm(21165):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x416efe40 self=0x41610850
06-03 22:04:53.883: I/dalvikvm(21165):   | sysTid=21165 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074737492
06-03 22:04:53.884: I/dalvikvm(21165):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1845 stm=250 core=1
06-03 22:04:53.884: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
06-03 22:04:53.884: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
06-03 22:04:53.884: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
06-03 22:04:53.884: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:445)
06-03 22:04:53.884: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:475)
06-03 22:04:53.884: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView.setBlankProfilePicture(ProfilePictureView.java:409)
06-03 22:04:53.884: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView.setProfileId(ProfilePictureView.java:222)
06-03 22:04:53.885: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at com.test.balls.ShowDetailsFragment.updateViews(ShowDetailsFragment.java:213)
06-03 22:04:53.885: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at com.test.balls.ShowDetailsFragment.onActivityCreated(ShowDetailsFragment.java:107)
06-03 22:04:53.885: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:892)
06-03 22:04:53.885: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
06-03 22:04:53.885: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-03 22:04:53.885: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
06-03 22:04:53.885: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
06-03 22:04:53.886: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
06-03 22:04:53.886: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:895)
06-03 22:04:53.886: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
06-03 22:04:53.886: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1234)
06-03 22:04:53.886: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
06-03 22:04:53.886: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
06-03 22:04:53.886: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-03 22:04:53.886: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-03 22:04:53.887: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-03 22:04:53.887: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
06-03 22:04:53.887: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
06-03 22:04:53.887: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-03 22:04:53.887: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
06-03 22:04:53.887: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
06-03 22:04:53.887: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-03 22:04:53.887: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-03 22:04:53.888: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-03 22:04:53.888: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
06-03 22:04:53.888: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
06-03 22:04:53.888: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-03 22:04:53.888: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
06-03 22:04:53.888: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
06-03 22:04:53.888: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1947)
06-03 22:04:53.888: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1137)
06-03 22:04:53.889: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1326)
06-03 22:04:53.889: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1024)
06-03 22:04:53.889: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5796)
06-03 22:04:53.889: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
06-03 22:04:53.889: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
06-03 22:04:53.889: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
06-03 22:04:53.889: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
06-03 22:04:53.889: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-03 22:04:53.890: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-03 22:04:53.890: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-03 22:04:53.890: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
06-03 22:04:53.890: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 22:04:53.890: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-03 22:04:53.890: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-03 22:04:53.890: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-03 22:04:53.890: I/dalvikvm(21165):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 22:04:53.891: D/skia(21165): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
06-03 22:04:53.893: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(21165): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.test.balls/databases/databaseplayers' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
06-03 22:04:53.896: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(21165): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.test.balls/databases/databaseplayers' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
06-03 22:04:53.898: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(21165): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.test.balls/databases/databaseplayers' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

I have just 3 fragments implemented in the viewpager and still the application crashes.
Please suggest me a way or an optimization technique to avoid this problem

Comment: what is inside 3 frgaments?

Comment: Do you have a big Bitmap in assets that you would like to show? Memory is limited on mobile :)

Comment: @mona the first fragment has 5 buttons and a facebookprofilepictureview second has 11 custom buttons and the third has 2 bitmaps and 2 textviews. but the error persists even when i dont show the 3rd fragment. Also

the program gets executed perfectly(i checked the sysout statements in my code) it just doesnt show up. the next time i run the app it runs the same class without a problem

Comment: ok any of them is doing http call? or network handling ? or heavy opetion? are u using asynctask?

Comment: @Kevinrob i dont have anything in my asset folder but i do have some big png files in drawable. but this gives error even after i dont show the fragment with those images

Comment: @mona there are certain http calls in the stating of the activity. i am using parse to get information for the user

Comment: yes plz use AsynsTask and call that, that will solve ur issues

Comment: @mona i have to get the data to the user when certain condition(defined in the code, do not use any httpcalls) are met. if they are met the database is updated with the data from parse otherwise the data is not updated. and when the app runs the first time there are series of things that user does and then starts the main class without those conditions true. and the app crashes(the first time ). But if i run the anyother time it runs without a glitch even if those conditions are true and the http calls are made

Comment: yes thats ok , but when the class are make make sure that is in Asynstask

Comment: @mona I am using big size bitmaps in a class before the class the app crashes could it be that that class eats up the memory. maybe thats the error

Comment: i guess that u can see from logcat itself